# Remove unused splash screens and icons from PhoneGap application

Tags: ios, cordova, icons, splash-screen

I have a very big app size. I tried to remove the default image files for unncesary splash screens and icons (i don´t support ipad). But i get a PBXCp error (like /icon-72.png: No such file or directory), even if i have configurated the proyect only for iphone, and i have removed ipad icons references on -Info.plist.

Anyone knows why i´m getting this error?

I want also to reduce the file size as possible. I have already removed the files of Capture.bundle, which i don´t need. Any other idea?

Thank you very much

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but also helps you with your problem. Have a look at http://imageoptim.com/ to minimize the size of your app bundle by compromising image files with just one click. Even well known apps like TweetBot are using this tool to reduce their app by multiple MBs!

Comment: It is also interesting what they say here http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html about disabling "Compress PNG Files" on "Build Settings".  I saved important amount of space

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1)

You still have a reference in your project to an "`icon-72.png`" file.

Check your project's build phases (e.g. the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase, especially) and also open up all the folders in your project to make sure there isn't a red (i.e. missing) file listed there.

2)

For larger graphics files, host the images or whatever on one of your servers and then have the app download and cache it.  That will help to reduce the initial download size.

Comment: Yes, i had a reference in "Copy Bundle Resources". Thank you so much!